# Stripe.Net "No Such Price Error" Error While Creating Stripe Session

Tags: c#, .net-core, stripe-payments

Hi im working on stripe subscription based session. I have created a Product on Stripe Dashboard and on session creating im passing hardcoded priceid and connected account id in the session but i m receiving bad request exception on creating the same session.

Here is my sample code as directed by this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration **in connect plateform and marketplaces After Section**

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "{ApiKey}";

            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
            {
                "card",
            },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
            {
                new SessionLineItemOptions
                {
                    Price = "{price_...}", //pricing id copied from dashboard
                  
                    
                },
            },
                Mode = "subscription",
                PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
                {
                    ApplicationFeeAmount = 20,
                },
                SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
                CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
            };

            var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
            {
                StripeAccount = "acct_...", // activated connected account id copied from dashboard
            };
            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions); // exception no such price found bad request
```

Comment: "No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account)

Comment: `Price = "{price_...}", //pricing id copied from dashboard`. Have you _literally_ got a `{` there?

Comment: @PaulAsjes i have only one account test account that is developer account.

Comment: @mjwills no curly brackets are there